# How to get value from the java map : Map<String,ArrayList<String>>?

Tags: java, dictionary

How to get the "value" from the java map :

```
    Map<String,ArrayList<String>> 
                       ^

                       ^

                       ^
                  This Value
```

Comment: Use yourMapName.get(key)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should [get() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) for that with key

> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if this map contains no mapping for the key.

```
ArrayList<String> value = yourMap.get(key);
```

*//where key is a string you used while putting*

Answer (score 0):

like this :

```
for(String key : map.keySet()) {
    ArrayList<String> value = map.get(key);
    for(String val : value) {
        System.out.println(val);
    }
}
```